# How to pass parameters in exec Oracle procedure which has array parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm Java background and new to oracle SQL
1.i'm creating the custom type and not sure is there other way ?
2.Created procedure UPSERT
3.While executing with exec command in SQL Developer throwing an error

Custom TYPE :

```
create or replace type temperature_ARRAY as table of number;                
create or replace type pressure_ARRAY as table of number;
```

Procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE flange_derating_upsert(i_flangecode IN VARCHAR2,i_product IN VARCHAR2,i_product_inch IN VARCHAR2,i_product_meterstyle IN VARCHAR2,i_pressure in pressure_ARRAY,i_temperature in temperature_ARRAY)
AS

begin
for i in i_temperature.FIRST..i_temperature.LAST loop
update xxcz_flange_ratings_mmi
set pressure = i_pressure(i),
LAST_UPDATED_by = 107009
where PRODUCT_NAME like '%'||i_product_inch||'%'||i_product_meterstyle||'%' and PC_MODEL_CODE = i_flangecode and temperature = i_temperature(i);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sql%rowcount||' '||i_temperature(i));
if sql%rowcount = 0 then
-- no rows were updated, so the record does not exist
insert into xxcz_flange_ratings_mmi (PRODUCT_NAME,PC_MODEL_CODE,TEMPERATURE,PRESSURE,LAST_UPDATED_BY) values(i_product,i_flangecode,i_temperature(i),i_pressure(i),107009);
end if;
end loop;
end flange_derating_upsert;
```

when execute : `exec flange_derating_upsert('A1','2 inch Quad High Pressure','2','Quad High Pressure',(275,235,215,195,170,140,125,110,95,80,65),(100,200,300,400,500,600,650,700,750,800,850));`

Getting below error :

```
Error starting at line : 32 in command -
BEGIN flange_derating_upsert('A1','2 inch Quad High Pressure','2','Quad High Pressure',(275,235,215,195,170,140,125,110,95,80,65),(100,200,300,400,500,600,650,700,750,800,850)); END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 1386:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FLANGE_DERATING_UPSERT'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 1386:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FLANGE_DERATING_UPSERT'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 1386:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 - "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause: Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing type reference while passing the arrays into the procedure,

try below,

```
BEGIN
   flange_derating_upsert('A1'
                         ,'2 inch Quad High Pressure'
                         ,'2'
                         ,'Quad High Pressure'
                         ,pressure_array(275, 235, 215, 195, 170, 140, 125, 110, 95, 80, 65)
                         ,temperature_array(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850));
END;
/
```

**OR**

```
exec flange_derating_upsert('A1','2 inch Quad High Pressure','2','Quad High Pressure',pressure_array(275,235,215,195,170,140,125,110,95,80,65),temperature_array(100,200,300,400,500,600,650,700,750,800,850));
```